# Action Cable Error: Subscription class not found in AnyCable server + How to Debug AnyCable on Prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, actioncable, anycable

I added a new channel to my Action Cable and it's working fine on my local machine. However, when deployed to the development environment, we encountered an error on the AnyCable server:

`E, [2024-03-06T12:34:46.645728 #1] ERROR -- : [AnyCable sid=oY1trubmcDzA0m-iyfezL] [ActionCable] [1594] Subscription class not found: "HeartbeatChannel" E, [2024-03-06T12:34:46.646192 #1] ERROR -- : Channel not found: HeartbeatChannel:`

We resolved this issue by restarting the GRPC service, AnyCable server, and the Rails instance. However, when deploying to production, the same issue persists, and our attempted solution doesn't work.

Could someone please advise on how to resolve this issue in the production environment? and also guide me through that how I can debug anycable on prod.

I tried searching on google, stack overflow and git hub but didn't get expected solution.

Comment: It seems that debugging AnyCable or interacting with it via a debug console or CLI is not possible. The error suggests that the latest changes are not being picked up, despite attempts to restart the AnyCable server, AnyCable-Go service, and Rails server. Since these actions did not resolve the issue, it appears to be an infrastructure-level problem that requires investigation at that level.